# zsh behaves weird in screen

Tags: screen, zsh

I have zsh set up as my default shell. It works fine as long as i am not within a `screen`. When i start `screen` it looks as if some dotfiles are not loaded. For example my `$PATH` isn't set correctly and some directories are missing. I'm not quite sure where to start looking. Since all is fine, as long as i'm not in a `screen`.

My dotfiles can be viewed on [github](http://github.com/nilsr/dotfiles). I also use oh-my-zsh — as you will notice.

Examples for weird behavior:

- The Theme looks slightly different (blue arrow where it should be white)
- Some directories in $PATH not set:

  `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/Nils/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin` VS. `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/Nils/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is this:

```
source ~/bin/dotfiles/zsh/*
source ~/bin/dotfiles/zsh/functions/*
```

The source command takes only one file parameter, the rest is taken as other arguments and not loaded, which means that only the first globbed file is sourced, not all of them. This didn't even work in a normal terminal, without screen. Try something like this instead:

```
for x in ~/bin/dotfiles/zsh/* ~/bin/dotfiles/zsh/functions/*; source $x
```

Comment: Still same behavior. I'll put a more detailed description of it in the question. The strange thing is also, that I cannot reproduce it somewhere else. It's just not working the way it should on my mac at work.